# Where should ember-cli-rails compile the app in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-rails

During `asset:precompile` ember-cli-rails will build the ember app into `tmp/ember-cli/apps/<appname>`. This places the app in `<appname>-<hash>.js` in the compiled app `assets` (that is in `tmp/ember-cli/<appname>/assets/<appname>-<hash>.js`). `include_ember_script_tags <:appname>` will ask for the correct `assets/<appname>-<hash>.js` but this will not be served by a productions server configured to let assets be served by Apache/Nginx.

Shouldn't the ember-cli-rails compile the app into `public/assets` in production mode, so they are visible to Apache/Nginx?

Or should I set rails to serve the app from where ember-cli-rails place it:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('tmp', 'ember-cli', 'apps', '<appname>', 'assets')
```

Comment: Good question, I've asked that also in to the Issue Tracker of ember-cli-rails: https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails/issues/505

Comment: FYI i ended up enhancing the 'assets:pre compile' task to copy the ember build artifacts into public

Answer (score 0):

Add this setting to `config/initializers/ember.rb` to compile the assets to the public folder.

```
# config/intializers/ember.rb                                                                                 
EmberCli.instance_variable_set(:@root, Rails.root.join("public/assets/ember-cli").tap(&:mkpath))
```